# Rigify IK Not Working Properly

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I've been working in a character during my free time, and I came to the point where I decided to Rig it using rigify. Everything went fine.. Until I tried bending the legs. Instead of bending like a normal character's legs would bend, the characters legs bent in the opposite Direction. I know that other people have come across this problem before, but there doesn't seem to be any IK constraints on any of the bones.

Please Help.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the IK bone on one of the hidden layers. :D

For anyone else with the same problem, the IK bones are on the second to panel in the layers area in the armature panel in properties

Comment: It would help anyone else with this problem if you edit the answer and clarify what and/or where actually is *"on the second to panel in the layers area in the armature panel in properties"*

Comment: "in the layers area in the armature panel in properties"    go to the armature panel in the properties tab, you will see multiple layers. its the second to last layer in the group of layers.